# Snowflake: Subtracting one column from another and partitioning it by another column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Data:

| Group | Date | Current | Next |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03/09/2020 | 4 | 7 |
| A | 04/09/2020 | 2 | 4 |
| A | 05/09/2020 | 4 | null |
| B | 17/08/2020 | 4 | 9 |
| B | 19/08/2020 | 4 | null |

I don't think I can use a Windows Function, as I'm not using SUM, COUNT, MAX, MIN etc. If I do just do NEXT- CURRENT, it's not going to partition by group. Hence, the whole set will be treated as one group.

I want to subtract Current from Next but for it to partitioned by Group.

Desired output:

| Group | Date | Current | Next | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03/09/2020 | 4 | 7 | 3 |
| A | 04/09/2020 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| A | 05/09/2020 | 4 | null | null |
| B | 17/08/2020 | 4 | 9 | 5 |
| B | 19/08/2020 | 4 | null | null |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just simple math, not sure what the real question is?

```
with data("Group", "Date", "Current", "Next") as (
select * from values
    
    ('A', '03/09/2020', 4, 7),
    ('A', '04/09/2020', 2, 4),
    ('A', '05/09/2020', 4, null),
    ('B', '17/08/2020', 4, 9),
    ('B', '19/08/2020', 4, null)
)
select *, "Next" - "Current" as Diff
from data;
```

| Group | Date | Current | Next | DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03/09/2020 | 4 | 7 | 3 |
| A | 04/09/2020 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| A | 05/09/2020 | 4 |  |  |
| B | 17/08/2020 | 4 | 9 | 5 |
| B | 19/08/2020 | 4 |  |  |